# Difference between model accuracy from test data and confusion matrix accuracy

Tags: nlp

- I am working for NLP project where I wanted to do text classification
  using neural n/w
- I am getting very nice accuracy from the test set as 98%.
- But, when I tried to check the confusion matrix accuracy (the accuracy score using confusion matrix) it's just 52%.
- How is it possible? What am I missing here?

## Question

What is the difference between both the accuracy's which one should be considered as the actual accuracy? and why?

## Code on test set

```
loss, acc = model.evaluate(Xtest, y_test_array)
```

Comment: It would be great if you provide the code that reproduces these numbers.

Comment: When I am doing "loss, acc = model.evaluate(Xtest, y_test_array)"  on test dataset I am getting 98% and when I am finding accuracy score from confusion matrix as "accuracy_score(y_test_class,pred)" then I am getting 51.17%.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your dataset has class imbalance, and the metric calculated from confusion matrix (it is NOT accuracy - probably, it is something like F1 score) is low because the minority class is recognized poorly. At the same time, accuracy is high because the majority class is recognized well.

Comment: Yes, I have few attributes which are having lesser samples but the difference is not greater than 20 samples. Also, I have lesser samples in test set. So, is it because of that? But I also have observed that there are many attributes having more samples are predicted wrongly to great extent.